# how to deal with different elements in a page(national weather) for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http="https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.05361000000005&lon=-118.24549999999999#.X06DsYtxXIU"

response=requests.get(http).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")


for questiones in soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container'):

    tag=questiones.find('p',class_='period-name').text
    print(tag)
    sit=questiones.find('p',class_="short-desc").text
    print(sit)
    temp = questiones.find('p', class_='temp temp-low').text
    print(temp)
    if temp ==True:
        print(temp)

    else:
        high=questiones.find('p',class_="temp temp-high").text
        print(high)
```

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with different elements in a page"?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: karthik...temp temp low and temp temp high.this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the element does not exist, you are trying to access the text attribute in NoneType. You should somehow check if you found the element like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http="https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.05361000000005&lon=-118.24549999999999#.X06DsYtxXIU"

response=requests.get(http).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")


for questiones in soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container'):

    tag=questiones.find('p',class_='period-name')
    if tag:
        print(tag.text)
    sit=questiones.find('p',class_="short-desc")
    if sit:
        print(sit.text)
    temp = questiones.find('p', class_='temp temp-low')
    if temp:
        print(temp.text)
    high=questiones.find('p',class_="temp temp-high")
    if high:
        print(high.text)
```

This prints:

```
Overnight
Patchy Fog
Low: 63 °F
Wednesday
Patchy Fogthen Sunny
High: 82 °F
WednesdayNight
Patchy Fog
Low: 63 °F
Thursday
Patchy Fogthen Sunny
High: 86 °F
ThursdayNight
Clear
Low: 65 °F
Friday
Sunny
High: 90 °F
FridayNight
Clear
Low: 73 °F
Saturday
Hot
High: 103 °F
SaturdayNight
Clear
Low: 78 °F
```

Comment: luigigi...thank you.it really helps.is there any other way?